# Is escaping image url ok?

Tags: html, image, xss

I've been (not so) accidentally escaping my image url's for a while now, and have never seen any issues in any browsers.

**eg, changing this:**

```
<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" />
```

**into this:**

```
<img src="http:&#x2F;&#x2F;example.com&#x2F;image.jpg" />
```

But I have been wondering if there could be issues with this. I've left this in place so far due to XSS concerns around where the image URL's come from, but I could regex validity check them and not escape them too..

It does make pages slightly bigger curently..

Has anyone experienced issues with escaping image URLs..?

Answer (score 1):

The "escaping" you're doing there is purely on the level of the XML/HTML, and by the time the document has been read and understood by the XML/HTML parser the escaping is gone -- long before any "URL-ness" even comes into play.

So, no, there shouldn't be any issues with that, but probably also not many benefits either :)

Comment: thanks.. makes sense.. my worry is that a XSS attack could be executed if the image url is not escaped. eg. an attacker could insert " /> <script..... into the url to do XSS...